# Batch convert xlsx to csv, all sheets with a pattern, if they have data, in linux

Tags: shell, csv, batch-processing, xlsx, ssconvert

I need to convert a lot of XLSX files to CSV, but each file has tabs, which must be converted to individual files if they have data in them.

In addition, I need to convert only those tabs that follow a pattern in their name, for example, "Tab1".

So far, I have managed to batch convert the files, although it only prints the first tab, using the ssconvert utility:

```
find. -name '* .xlsx' -exec ssconvert -T Gnumeric_stf: stf_csv {} \;
```

But when I try to add the tabs flag (`-S`) or the flag to include those tabs with a pattern (`-I`), I only get the following message:

```
find. -name '* .xlsx' -exec ssconvert -S -I tab1 -T Gnumeric_stf: stf_csv {} \;
```

> An output file name or an explicit export type is required.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What if you remove `-I`? According to [what I find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ssconvert.1.html), it seems to mean something different than "include only specific tabs".

Comment: `-name '* .xlsx'` - your files have a space before extension?

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution, I leave it here in case someone finds it useful. In the end I created a small script that performs the actions:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.xlsx; do
    nombre=${i:0:${#i}-5};
    name="$nombre-%n-%s.csv";
    ssconvert --export-type=Gnumeric_stf:stf_csv --export-file-per-sheet $i $name; 
done
echo "Finish!"
```